# Drawing Signal Flow Graph from Bridged-T Network

Tags: control-system, bridge

I am confused about where to place R1. Is it a feed-forward or feedback term? Y1 and Y2 are admittances representing the capacitors.

[image: Signal Flow Graph]

Answer (score 0):

I think is ok as graph nut you have to use Gx=1/Rx in each branch, check this out http://dknollman.50webs.com/k9analysis/Signal_Flow.html
[image]